# Straddled sequences formulation of derivative

Tags: real-analysis

I've been dealing with this problem this week but I don't know how to start. Suppose $f$ a real valued continuous function at $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Also suppose that for every pair of sequences $x_{n}, y_{n}$ with $\lim x_{n}=\lim y_{n}=a$ and $x_{n}<a<y_{n}$ the limit 
$\displaystyle \lim \frac{f(x_{n})-f(y_{n})}{x_{n}-y_{n}}$ exists and equals $L$. Show that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and that $f'(a)=L$. Thanks for the Help.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\alpha_n={y_n-a\over y_n-x_n}>0,\beta_n={a-x_n\over y_n-x_n}>0,\alpha_n+\beta_n=1$

$\frac{f(x_{n})-f(y_{n})}{x_{n}-y_{n}}-f'(a)=[g(y_n)-f'(a)]\alpha_n+[g(x_n)-f'(a)]\beta_n$

where $g(x)={f(x)-f(a)\over x-a}$

Comment: How do you guarantee the existence of $f'(a)$?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I assumed that! you can downvote my answer!